# How can I run this simple script on GPU (using PyOpenCL)

Tags: python

I have a Radeon AMD GPU, and would like to improve the speed of this script:

```
from cryptotools.BTC.HD import check, WORDS

with open("combo.txt", "r") as a_file:
for line in a_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    for word in WORDS:
        mnemonic = stripped_line.format(x=word)
        if check(mnemonic):
            print(mnemonic)
             with open("print.txt", "a") as i:
                 i.write(mnemonic)
                 i.write("\n")
```

Ideas on how to improve the speed of the script are also welcome

Comment: It's maybe not what you want, but if you really need speed, then you should use c++. python is pretty slow.

Comment: Okay, here is the 100 million dollar question: How do I change the above code to c++?

Comment: If you don't know it, that wouldn't help you xD Another idea is to have a look at multithreading. It's pretty easy to do in python and will those bruteforcing programs a giant boost. Good Luck on bruteforcing wallet seeds :)

Comment: I am trying to solve a seed based puzzle :D, why dont you modify the code for to implement multi-threatening?

Comment: It won't help you to just copy and paste code without understanding it. You will get in trouble with the next problem. I recommend to read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm After that you will be able to solve different seeds with the same function simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks man, and you are right! Take it easy :)